# WPF adding rectangles on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

The code below does not adding rectangle. Can anyone advice What i missed ?  `mainCanvas.Children.Add(rectangle[i]);` does not work.
RoomX.Count = 5 how I can go with for add all five rectangles with different width and height which is in RoomX, RoomY

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     HProDataContext db = new HProDataContext();

     var RoomX = (from d in db.rooms select d.sizex).ToList();
     var RoomY = (from d in db.rooms select d.sizey).ToList();

     for (int i = 0; i < RoomX.Count; i++)
     {
          var random = new Random();
          var rectangle = new Rectangle()
          {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                Fill = Brushes.SkyBlue,
                Width = Convert.ToDouble(RoomX),
                Height = Convert.ToDouble(RoomY),
                Margin = new Thickness(left: random.NextDouble() * 300,
                                       top: random.NextDouble() * 150,
                                       right: 0,
                                       bottom: 0),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            };
            mainCanvas.Children.Add(rectangle);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Width = Convert.ToDouble(RoomX),
Height = Convert.ToDouble(RoomY),
```

Are you sure that's what you want to do? You're converting a list to a double there, which seems kinda off.

I think you need something like:

```
Width = Convert.ToDouble(RoomX[i]),
Height = Convert.ToDouble(RoomY[i]),
```